# Parallel file upload using jMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to create a jMeter script to perform file upload operation to a web application:

Test Plan
    Thread Group
        Launch application
        Login
        Navigate
        Upload
        Logout

In above case when we have multiple thread group then multiple files are getting uploaded. Although my requirement is to perform multiple upload operation (in parallel) in one thread operation.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You only need one thread group for your requirements. Just set more users in that thread group and don't set ramp-up time. They will all login as fast as they can and do all the steps you have in your test plan. This would be the simplest way.

But, if you want all of them uploading at the exactly same moment, you can add [If controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) (preferably with [While controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)) to check if all of them have passed "Navigate" request and then enable the controller once all of them are ready for upload. This can be achieved by setting up counter which is increased when "Navigate" request is done, and once counter is equal to number of users, tell then to upload.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot upload more than 1 file at a time using single thread
2. You cannot jump over threads number you've defined for the Thread Group

So the options are in:

- Use multiple threads and [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) to ensure that file upload is executed at exactly the same moment
- Do some scripting with i.e. [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) in order to trigger multiple file uploads from one thread, just like [simulating AJAX calls with JMeter](http://How%20to%20Load%20Test%20AJAX/XHR%20Enabled%20Sites%20With%20JMeter)